# Is there a way to pass in callbacks when calling Async methods in WP8/Silverlight

Tags: c#, .net, silverlight, windows-8, windows-phone-8

I've been writing Windows Phone 8 code that calls a SOAP web service backend.  From what I've read, the typical pattern is this:

```
var client = new KitchenPCSoapClient();

client.LogonCompleted += client_LogonCompleted;
client.LogonAsync(username, password);
```

To me, this just seems counter intuitive.  If I call `LogonAsync` multiple times with the same client, I don't necessarily want it to use the same `LogonCompleted` callback every time.

What I'd like is a pattern more like JavaScript, where you pass in a reference to the callback function.  More like:

```
var client = new KitchenPCSoapClient();
client.LogonAsync(username, password, client_LogonCompleted);
```

Is there a way to implement such a pattern, or should I just force myself to get used to setting the `LogonCompleted` property before I call `LogonAsync`, or set the `userState` property if I want to differentiate between different contexts?

Answer (score 0):

You can make use of Dispatcher and call the function on UI side for this ...

I am doing like this

callback function

```
private void AddPricesHandler(CompletedEventArgs response, Exception e)
{
  //your code gose here
}
```

Call proxy calss function

```
Proxy.AddData(AddPricesHandler, request);
```

proxy class calling webservice

```
public void AddData(Action<CompletedEventArgs, Exception> callback, IPVWorkflowService.CreateEditDeletePriceSourceRequest request)
        {
            _workflowProxy.CreateEditDeletePriceSourceAsync(request, callback);
            _workflowProxy.CreateEditDeletePriceSourceCompleted+=new EventHandler<CreateEditDeletePriceSourceCompletedEventArgs>(_workflowProxy_CreateEditDeletePriceSourceCompleted); 
        }
```

completer function use dispatcher to call callback function

```
    void _workflowProxy_CreateEditDeletePriceSourceCompleted(object sender, CreateEditDeletePriceSourceCompletedEventArgs e)
    {
        try
        {
            this.dispatcher.BeginInvoke((Action)(() =>
            {
                (e.UserState as Action<CompletedEventArgs, Exception>)(e, null);
            }));
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            this.dispatcher.BeginInvoke((Action)(() =>
            {
                (e.UserState as Action<CompletedEventArgs, Exception>)(e, ex);
            }));
        }
        finally
        {
            _workflowProxy.CreateEditDeletePriceSourceCompleted -= _workflowProxy_CreateEditDeletePriceSourceCompleted;
            _workflowProxy = null;
        }
    }
```

Comment: Please don't forget to remove the event handler. Else the service client will never be cleaned up.

Comment: I don't think this method works with the Silverlight proxy classes..  There's nothing that takes an `Action<>` parameter.

Comment: @MikeChristensen - i created my own proxy class as wrapper for the proxy class generated by adding reference ...

Answer (score 0):

The beauty of Async/Await is that you don't have to write callbacks, you just write code that looks like synchronous, but in the background it's executed asynchronously:

```
var client = new KitchenPCSoapClient();
await client.LogonAsync(username, password);

// you get here after the async logon is completed
// do stuff after logon
```

But if you really want to use callbacks, you can just use the method ContinueWith on the Task object, that is returned from asynchronous method:

```
var client = new KitchenPCSoapClient();
Task task = client.LogonAsync(username, password);

// this method is called when async execution of task is finished
task.ContinueWith(client_LogonCompleted);
```

Comment: Won't even compile.  It says *"The 'await' operator can only be used within an async method.  Consider marking this method with the 'async' modifier and changing its return return to 'Task'."* -- I think the Silverlight proxy classes don't support this, otherwise I'm sure it would be a good approach.

Comment: If the service reference is not based on async/await, then you cannot use this approach, unless you create your own async based wrapper over your service.

Comment: So you're saying don't use the auto-generated proxy code that Visual Studio creates, and write everything from scratch?  That sounds like a lot of work..

Comment: @MikeChristensen: VS2012 auto-generated proxies should include `Async` methods that return `Task` (are you possibly using a proxy from an older version?). If you don't want to change the proxy, you can use `Task.Factory.FromAsync` to wrap `BeginLogin`/`EndLogin` into a `Task`.

Comment: @StephenCleary - Nope, they return void.  I'm using VS2012, Win8, and .NET 4.5.  All the latest and greatest stuff.

Comment: @MikeChristensen: Did you generate the proxy with VS2012? Do you have `Begin*`/`End*` available?

Comment: You probably need the Async Targeting Pack for Silverlight.  This lets you use C# 5.0 keywords with Silverlight async libraries. http://10rem.net/blog/2012/05/22/using-async-and-await-in-silverlight-5-and-net-4-in-visual-studio-11-with-the-async-targeting-pack

Comment: The current version of "Async targeting pack" is this: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/bclteam/archive/2012/10/19/using-async-await-without-net-framework-4-5.aspx